# Silverlight 4 and Implicit styling

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In Silverlight 4 it's possible to use implicit styling - and that is amazing! But what if I want to apply a style to all of my Buttons, CheckBoxes and RadioButtons (all inheriting from ButtonBase)? I can't set TargetType on the Style to ButtonBase - that doesn't work. Do I need to create a style to each of the 3 control types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx
Try this

Comment: OK so it's not possible :(

Quote from the link: "Note, that the TargetType must match exactly for a typed style to be applied. For example, if you specify the Style’s Key, then it’s ok for the target element to be a subclass of the TargetType. But a typed style typically gets applied to elements which type matches exactly! This is done to prevent surprises. For example, you might have created a Style for all ToggleButtons in your application and you don’t want this style to be applied to any CheckBoxes (which derives from the ToggleButton)."

Comment: yups that is the case to prevent unwanted surprises of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

xamlgeek,

The following implicit styles work well for me.  I first create some name/keyed styles, using common BasedOn styles whereever possible.  Then I simply create the implicit styles BasedOn those named/keyed styles...

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FontBrush}" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="BaseStyleCentered" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CommonCheckBox" TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyleCentered}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CommonRadioButton" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyleCentered}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CommonButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyleCentered}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,10,0" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource ButtonWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHeight}" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonCheckBox}">
</Style>
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonRadioButton}">
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonButton}">
</Style>
```

Good luck,

Jim

YinYangMe, YinYangMoney and FaceToFaceSoftware

Comment: Your styles are no implicit styles. These are named styles. Implicit styles have no key and only a TargetType

Comment: @Jehof: Sorry, I fixed my explanation in the code snippet above